# How do I add new information to the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

I am working with the following code. I have set up the form, models, and controllers necessary to add an item. I know the code works because after entering text into the text field I am redirect to the correct page. My question is: How do I add the text entered by the user into the default database?

```
    public ActionResult TruckAdd()
    {
        ViewBag.DisplayText = "Add A Truck";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TruckAdd(RegisterTruckModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the Truck
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: This might be of some help to you: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1. You have to setup your database first to store the data (create a Truck table, or use Entity Framework code first)

Comment: yeah, you can learn about basic of mvc from asp.net/mvc/tutorials